# Do fire extinguishers count as 'explosives'?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, the-missing-link

I finished The Missing Link recently, without firing a shot, throwing a grenade or mine, or using a Praxis Point. I thought this would qualify me for the Factory Zero achievement, which follows: "You survived The Missing Link using no Praxis kits, weapons, or explosives. Whoa."

I didn't get the achievement, though. I'm wondering if this is maybe because an enemy got hit by an errant fire extinguisher or explosive barrel at some point. (I can't seem to leave them be) Can anyone confirm or deny this for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. This is from my personal experience. I went through the whole DLC without using (or even drawing) a single weapon, lobbing a single grenade or using a praxis kit. Yet the achievement didn't pop for me in the end. The only non-takedown kill I had was chucking a fire extinguisher at two pursuing enemies. By process of elimination, fire extinguishers count either as weapons or explosives.

The achievement popped for me on my second playthrough, which was identical to the first without the fire extinguisher-chucking part.

Just a side note, explosive barrels also count as explosives.

Comment: Thanks. It's not classified as an explosive ingame, but it is.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll have to be more careful about throwing things around.